# I don't know how to login in this php file

Tags: php

This code start with:

```
class Autentificare {
    function __construct($user, $parola) {
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->parola=$parola;
    }

    function check() {
        if ($this->user == "admin" && $this->parola == "123") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I login in this file? This file requires those username and password and I don't know how to put in the link to access the file.

Comment: Please provide some background for your question.
Is this your code?
If this is not your code did the code come from an open source project you can reference?
Please explain the process you are following to authenticate & possibly why?

Answer (score 1):

Enter the code `Autentificare("admin","123")` and it should work, I think.

With that in mind, no real system should have only one user and unencrypted passwords.  You should look into cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: I didn't explain too well. I don't know how to login in this php file, and when I acces: site.com/file.php it requires login. I recieve the text "You don't have acces to this area", and I must to put something in the link .php? something I think so.

Comment: @user3684939 - look in the code you've provided. It doesn't include the text "You don't have acces to this area"; so whatever the problem is, it's outside the scope of the code you've provided. What's the PHP for the file at `site.com/file.php`?

Comment: What should I do to acces the file from link?

Comment: @user3684939 So, according to the code you shared, it looks like this is from phpbb ... I recommend you modify your question to clarify you are having phpbb authentication issues.
Additionally, what are you attempting to do with phpbb?

Comment: if you go to file.php?4m_user=admin&4m_pass=123 it should log in.

Answer (score 0):

I am & I believe Scelesto is also, assuming that you are writing this code.
With that assumption, in order to use a class you must instantiate an object.
You would do this with this bit of code:

```
$Autentificare = new Autentificare("admin","123");
```

After you instantiate it you would need to call it's check() method like this:

```
$authenticationResult = $Autentificare->check();
if($authenticationResult)
{
  echo 'you are authenticated!';
}
else
{
  echo 'you are NOT authenticated!';
}
```

Finally as Scelesto mentioned, this seems to be highly insecure.
You should never know, nor should you be passing, the password itself.
The password should be hashed and stored in a database.
When a user enters a password it should be hashed as well.
The two hashes should then be compared by your code.

If this is not your code then I would recommend attempting to get a hold of the person/group that wrote it (documentation, email, forums etc...).

Here' is an article on creating a reasonably secure PHP application: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: Here is all the code:


What I must to do to acces the file?